# If f = O(h) and g = Ω(h) then f+g is?

Tags: big-o-notation

Is the answer O(h) or Ω(h) for **f+g?**
My professor says its Ω(h), but I can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that $f(n)$ is non-negative.

From $g(n) \in \Omega(h(n))$ you know that there is some $n_0$ and some $c$ such that, for all $n \ge n_0$, $$g(n) \ge  c \cdot h(n).$$ Then:
$$f(n) + g(n) \ge g(n) \ge c \cdot h(n) \quad \text{ for all } n \ge n_0.$$ Therefore $f(n)+g(n) \in \Omega(h(n))$.

Comment: isn't f(n) ≤ h(n) so why can't we write it as ()+()≤f()≤⋅ℎ() for all ≥0.

Comment: $f(n) + g(n) \le f(n)$ is false for all $g(n)$ that are not asymptotically $0$.
Pick $f(n) = 1$,  $g(n) = n^2$, and $h(n) = n$ as an example and check where it breaks down (you can use, e.g., $n_0=1$ and $c=1$).

Comment: if h(n) = n shouldn't O(h)= n^2 or something bigger?

Comment: I don't know what $O(h)=n^2$ means. $O(h(n))$ denotes a set of functions. $f(n) = O(h(n))$ is a common abuse of notation for $f(n) \in O(h(n))$. It makes no sense to say that a set is equal to a function. $O(h(n))$ is the set of all functions $z(n)$ such that $z(n) \le c \cdot h(n)$ for some constant $c \ge 0$ and for all sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$f+g$ being larger than $g$, the lower bound of $g$ still holds. And we know nothing about the upper bound.