# If we have f(n) ∈ O(h(n)) and g(n) ∈ Ω(h(n)), does that mean that f(n) + g(n) ∈ Θ(h(n))?

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

It is quite easy to prove that f(n) + g(n) ∈ Ω(h(n)), but I am having trouble with proving/disproving that f(n) + g(n) ∈ O(h(n)).

Someone suggested that [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/158890/if-f-oh-and-g-%CE%A9h-then-fg-is) answers mine, which it doesn't. As I've written above, proving that f(n) + g(n) ∈ Ω(h(n)) is easy. I am having trouble disproving that f(n) + g(n) ∈ O(h(n)).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The answer to your previous question also answers this. Don't cheat by changing your ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If f = O(h) and g = Ω(h) then f+g is?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/158890/if-f-oh-and-g-%ce%a9h-then-fg-is)

Comment: What do you mean? I created this profile today and I've never asked a question before.

As far as that link answering my question, it doesn't. As I've written in the post, I can easily prove that f(n) + g(n) ∈ Ω(h(n)), but I am unable to disprove that f(n) + g(n) ∈ O(h(n)).

Comment: Anyway, the other post does answer.

Comment: The post answers only one half of my question. In order for f(n) + g(n) ∈ Θ(h(n)) to hold, I need to prove that f(n) + g(n) ∈ Ω(h(n)) AND f(n) + g(n) ∈ O(h(n)). The other post proves only the first part, but it doesn't prove/disprove the second part. Do you see my issue?

Comment: For the last time, "we know nothing about the upper bound."

Comment: Ok I get it now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"We know nothing about the upper bound" is a good intuition but it is not a formal proof that you can't hope to show $f(n) + g(n) \in O(h(n))$ if your only assumptions are $f(n) \in O(h(n))$ and $g(n) \in \Omega(h(n))$.

Fortunately, a counterexample is easily obtained by considering, e.g., $f(n)=1$, $g(n)=n^2$, and $h(n)=n$.

Comment: Great, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Yves Daoust](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/16034/yves-daoust) for providing the [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/159137/159436). We know nothing about the upper bound of f(n) + g(n) so we cannot prove f(n) + g(n) ∈ O(h(n)).